# Android: Issue with transparent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, transparent

Recently, on one of our production apps, transparent activity has stopped working.
By this I mean that it became a black background instead of transparent. When I set activity's background color to solid one (i.e. red, green etc.), it's applied w/o issues.
Probably the issue was caused by migration to AndroidX, but I don't have evidences for this.

After many hours of debugging, testing and reading through related SO topics, I was finally able to identify circumstances, under which the issue is happening.

My test environment is a [very simple clean project with two activities](https://github.com/mirokolodii/DebugTransparentActivity) (you can check full code under the link).

**Conditions for working state**

I'm able to make second activity transparent only if my 'themes.xml' file is very simple. You can see first activity in the background:

[image]

**Conditions for non-working state**

It's enough to add a simple style, even without items inside and with no parents, to cause background to be black instead of transparent:

[image]

Here is my 'themes.xml':

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <!--    By removing this style I can make transparent activity to work -->
    <style name="ScrollViewStyle" />

</resources>
```

And 'AndroidManifest.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
            android:theme="@style/Transparent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope someone will be able to help me getting technical explanation of this strange behavior.

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround, I was able to make activity transparent by setting its theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` directly in Manifest. Note 'directly', as it will not work, if I even create custom empty theme with above mentioned theme as a parent.
But this solution has limitations:

- not possible to customize behavior, like using Dialog enter/exit transition animations etc.
- activity should extend Android Activity, and not AppCompatActivity.
- I also had to set transparent background for a root view of this activity to achieve transparency.

Comment: Hope you get this message - this was an amazing tip, thanks!   This bizarre problem appears to have resurfaced in 4.2RC1.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041191/updated-to-4-2rc1-and-transparent-activities-do-not-work-suddenly-black

Comment: This helped me figure out a workaround too.

Comment: It's weird that inheriting it in another style causes the background to become black.

Answer (score 0):

After some refactoring (AndroidX) in a project it occurred in an activity for us when using the setLayout property. We needed the WRAP_CONTENT property from LayoutParams. But instead of importing it from WindowManager.LayoutParams it was imported from ActionBar.LayoutParams that caused the black background - no matter what style settings you had. We changed it from ActionBar to WindowManager and then it worked. Hope this may help someone out there.